# WebSocket connection failed - JHipster on Kubernetes

Tags: jhipster, microk8s

I run JHipster app on Kubernetes [microk8s] with ingress on remote host.

Ingress sets by default https.

In browser console I get:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://XXXXXX/websocket/tracker/041/tjk33h4t/websocket?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403`
followed by

`Refused to display 'https://XXXXX/websocket/tracker/iframe.html?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'`

In application-prod.yml I have:

```
  port: 8080
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
    min-response-size: 1024
```

When I type  http [not https] url followed by port set by kubernetes service - works fine.

In microk8s ingress

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

doesn't seem to work anyway.

How can I get to work websocket from https front-end?

Answer (score 0):

you can use try adding annotation for websocket service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: tls-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: SERVICE_NAME
    nginx.org/websocket-services: SERVICE_NAME
```